# Using Torquebox to send messages to the browser

Tags: websocket, jrubyonrails, hornetq, torquebox

So our team has recently implemented torquebox into our jruby on rails applications. The purpose of this was to be able to receive queue/topic messages from an outside source which is streaming live data.

We have setup our queues/topics and they are receiving the messages without an issue. The next step we want to take is to get these messages on the browser.

So we started to look into leveraging the power of stomp. But we have come across some issues with this. It seems from the documentation that the purpose of using stomp + websockets is to receive messages from the client-side and push those messages to other clients. But we want to receive messages on our queues, and then push these messages to the client-side using websockets. Is this possible? Or would we have to implement a different technology such as Pusher or socket.io to get the queue/topic messages to the browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your other question?

Comment: this question I am asking if messages on the queue can be sent to the browser through stomplets. Where my other question was how to run the stomp websocket server

Answer (score 0):

I think stomplets is good solution for this task. In rails application you should use ruby base stomp client, in browser javascript base stomp client. In rails just send data, and in browser just receive.
More detail how do it you can find in torquebox documentation
http://torquebox.org/documentation/2.0.0/stomp.html

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to push messages straight from the server to clients. It took me quite a bit of digging to find it as it is not listed in the documentation directly. Their blog lists it in their example of how to build a chat client using websockets.

http://torquebox.org/news/2011/08/23/stomp-chat-demo-part3/

Basically you use the `inject` method to choose which channel you're publishing to, and then use the `publish` method on the returned object to actually send the message. This code excerpt from the article should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
inject( '/topics/chat' ).publish( message, 
                                  :properties=>{ 
                                    :recipient=>username, 
                                    :sender=>'system' 
                                   } )
```

It looks like `:properties` is the same thing as message headers. I'll be giving this a go over the next couple of days to see how well this works in Rails.